# A property of the wedge of the restriction of a $2$-form and a $1$-form to a codimension $1$ vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $\omega \in \Lambda^2(V^*)$ be a $2$-form on a vector space $V$ of dimension $2k+2$. Suppose further we have a nonzero $1$-form $\eta$ on $V$ and a subspace $W$ of codimension $1$ with the property that $W = V_1 \oplus (\ker (\eta|_W))$ for some $V_1$ of dimension $1$.  Is it true then that $\eta|_W \wedge (\omega|_W)^k \neq 0$ iff $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}$ is nondegenerate?

I can assume that $\omega$ is nondegenerate on $V$ if it is a necessary hypothesis somewhere.

I suspect the answer to be "Yes", because if $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}$ is nondegenerate, by the pointwise Darboux theorem we have that on $\ker(\eta|_W)$ we can write $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)} = \sum_{i=1}^{2k} e_i^* \wedge f_i^*$ with $\omega(e_i, e_j) = 0 = \omega(f_i, f_j)$ and $\omega(e_i, f_j) = \delta_{i,j}$. Since on $W$ $\eta$ is nonzero, it seems plausible that when I write out the wedge product $\eta|_W \wedge (\omega|_W)^k$ I cannot get a $0$.

However, I don't know how to pass from the expression I have for $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}$ to an expression for $\omega|_W$, nor how to write the wedge product in a convenient way so that I can show it's nonzero.

The only true problem seems to be that I don't see how to use the expression of $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}$ to derive an expression for $\omega|_W$; if this were solved, I think the problem would also be solved just by the fact that $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}^k \neq 0$ iff $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}$ is nondegenerate (which follows from Darboux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in general derive an expression for $\omega|_W$ using the expression of $\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)}$. Taking the basis $v_0, ..., v_{2k+1}$, and its dual basis $v_0^*, ..., v_{2k+1}^*$, where $v_0$ is the basis of $V_0$, $v_1$ is the basis of $V_1$, $(v_2, ..., v_{2k+1})$ is the basis of $ker(\eta|_W)$, and $V = V_0 \oplus W = V_0 \oplus V_1 \oplus ker(\eta|_W)$, you have:

$\eta = Av_0^* + Bv_1^*$

$\eta|_W = Bv_1^*$

$\omega = \sum_{0 \le i<j \le 2k+1} C_{i,j}v_i^*\wedge v_j^*$

$\omega|_W = \sum_{1 \le i<j \le 2k+1} C_{i,j}v_i^*\wedge v_j^*$

$\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)} = \sum_{2 \le i<j \le 2k+1} C_{i,j}v_i^*\wedge v_j^*$

It's clear to see that having an expression for $\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)}$ doesn't give you any information regarding $C_{i,j}$ for $i<2$.

Nonetheless, the answer to your question is yes. You showed that if $\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)}$ is non-degenerate, then $\eta|_W \wedge \omega|_W \ne 0$. For the other direction, assume that $\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)}$ is degenerate, and we'll show that $\eta|_W \wedge \omega|_W = 0$. The degeneracy gives that $(\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)})^k = 0$. Therefore, all the terms of $(\omega|_W)^k$ (when written in the basis above), that have nonzero coefficients, must have $v_1^*$ in them. Hence, when wedged with $\eta|_W$, we get zero, which proves the other direction.

Comment: If $x_i$ are basis vectors for a vector space, what does $dx_i$ mean? I suspect you just mean the dual basis? This is highly nonstandard notation.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I messed up the notation

Comment: I confused coordinates with the basis vectors. I edited it, is it better?

Comment: You should make it clear that you're letting $v_i^*$ denote the dual basis. I'm not thinking about the problem, but why do your indices go only to $k$ and not to $2k+1$?

Comment: You're right, thank you again! :)

Comment: With your observations for how we can write $\eta$ and $\omega$, I was able to make a calculation and it came out to be that $\eta|_W \wedge \omega|_W$ has the same expression as $\omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}$. Is this the gist of the proof? I'll post the calculation below, I'd just like to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(\omega|_W)^2 =  \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i < j \leq 2k+1
\\1 \leq s< r \leq 2k+1
}} c_{i,j} c_{s,r} v_i^* \wedge v_j^* \wedge v_s^* \wedge v_r^*
$$
Generalising,
$$
(\omega|_W)^k = \sum_{\substack{1\leq i_s < j_s \leq 2k+1 \\ s=1}}^k
c_{i_1, j_1} \cdots c_{i_k, j_k} v_{i_1}^* \wedge v_{j_1}^* \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{i_k}^* \wedge v_{j_k}^*
$$

By the same reasoning:
$$
(\omega|_K)^k = \sum_{\substack{2\leq i_s < j_s \leq 2k+1 \\ s=1}}^k
c_{i_1, j_1} \cdots c_{i_k, j_k} v_{i_1}^* \wedge v_{j_1}^* \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{i_k}^* \wedge v_{j_k}^*
$$

Now because $\eta|_W = B v_1^*$ we have:
$$
(\eta|_W) \wedge (\omega|_W)^k =  \sum_{\substack{1\leq i_s < j_s \leq 2k+1 \\ s=1}}^k
c_{i_1, j_1} \cdots c_{i_k, j_k} B v_1^* \wedge v_{i_1}^* \wedge v_{j_1}^* \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{i_k}^* \wedge v_{j_k}^*
$$

Since in every wedge product we have $e_1^*$, if some $i_s = 1$ then the product disappears. Therefore we are left with:
$$
(\eta|_W) \wedge (\omega|_W)^k = \omega|_{\ker(\eta|_W)}
$$

Comment: In the last equation I suppose you mean: $\eta|_W \wedge (\omega|_W) ^k = \eta|_W \wedge (\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)} ) ^k$.

Comment: But yes, that's the idea

Comment: @ReiHenigman Yes, that is what I meant. The last problem I have now is, why is it true that if $\eta|_W \wedge (\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)} ) ^k = 0$ then $(\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)} ) ^k = 0$? Intuitively it should be because $\eta|_W \neq 0$ and it is linearly independent from $(\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)} ) ^k $ if the latter is nonzero. But is it true that for some general elements of an exterior algebra, their wedge product is nonzero if and only if they are linearly independent? I can't seem to find this referenced anywhere

Comment: It is true in that case, but it's not because they're linearly independent. Take for example $dx\wedge dy$ and $dx \wedge dz$. They are linearly independent, and they're both non-zero, but their wedge is zero. It is true in this case because expressing them using the basis you have $\eta|_W = Bv_1^*$ and $(\omega|_{ker(\eta|_W)})^k = C v_2^* \wedge ... \wedge v_{2k+1}^*$, so their wedge is exactly $BCv_1^* \wedge ... \wedge v_{2k+1}^*$ and this is zero if and only if $B$ or $C$ is zero.

Comment: I think you can however explain it in a way that sits with the linear-independent intuition: you can say something like $\eta|_W$ is in the subspace $\Lambda^1(V_1^*) \subset \Lambda^1(W^*)$ and $(\omega_{ker(\eta|_W)})^k$ is in the subspace $\Lambda^{2k}((ker(\eta|_W))^*) \subset \Lambda^{2k}(W^*)$, and so their wedge is non-zero iff they're both non-zero, and to prove this claim by choosing a basis, in the same spirit as my previous comment... Not sure if it's helping or hurting the intuition :)